# logarithm properties problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

The problem in question is:

$3^{x+3} = 5e^{7x}$

I have tried:

$(x+3) *ln(3) = 7x *ln(5)$

$ln(3)/ln(5) = 7x/(x+3)$

And that is where I stall out. I assume it is because I made an error somewhere along the way. Would anyone mind pointing it out?

Comment: $\ln(5e^{7x})=\ln 5+  \ln e^{7x}= \ln 5+ 7x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ 3^{x+3} = 5e^{7x} $$

$$ (x+3)\ln 3 = \ln(5e^{7x}  ) = \ln 5 + 7x $$

$$ x\ln 3 - 7x = \ln 5 - 3\ln 3 \Rightarrow x(\ln 3 - 7) = \ln 5 - 3\ln 3 \Rightarrow x = \frac{\ln 5 - 3\ln 3}{\ln 3 - 7} $$